# Combination of arrangement and probability

Tags: probability, permutations, combinations

Four guys and four girls are arranged in a row such that no two girls are together. What is the probability that any two of the four guys are together?

Comment: Have you tried counting the number of cases of no two adjacent girls by the principle of inclusion-exclusion?

Comment: No. Please elaborate.

Answer (score 1):

Use the laws for conditional probability: $ \displaystyle P(A | B) = \frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)} $.

In this problem, the total number of cases is simply $ 8! $ (which will eventually cancel out).

If no two girls are together, then there must be at least one guy between each of them. The last guy then has 5 possible positions - before the first girl, between first and second, and so forth. Hence, this has $ 4! \cdot 4! \cdot 5 $ possibilities.

Now, if no two guys are together, then the fourth guy has to be either before the first girl or after the last, so there are $ 4! \cdot 4! \cdot 2 $ possibilities.

Hence, the answer is $ \displaystyle \frac{\frac{4! \cdot 4! \cdot 2}{8!}}{\frac{4! \cdot 4! \cdot 5}{8!}} = \frac{2}{5} $.

Comment: That sounds like you meant "exactly two". If girls A,B,C are together, then the two girls A and B are sitting together. Please edit your question.

Comment: You are right. It does mean that no two girls ever sit together. So  there has to be at least one boy between any two of them. So, g g g g has 5 places for 4 boys. But 2/5 is not the answer

Comment: THe answer is 1-(2/5) for any two guys being together. Thanks!

Comment: Right, I calculated the probability that no two guys are together. Forgot about that last little detail, as the requirement for boys is opposite the requirement for girls.